# A problem with dynamically created image

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I have problem with dynamically created image (JavaScript).
I want to change the innerHTML property of a table cell:

```
   var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows;
   var y=x[0].cells;

   var myImg = document.createElement('img');
   myImg .setAttribute("alt","");
   myImg .setAttribute("style","vertical-align: middle; visibility:visible");
   myImg .setAttribute("src", "http://valid_link/ajax-loader.gif");

   y[0].innerHTML = myImg ;
```

but, as the result I see "[object HTMLImageElement]". How to show that picture ?

Comment: Incidentally, you should also avoid `setAttribute` on HTML documents, as it doesn't work right for many attributes in IE. The `style` above won't work, for example. Just use DOM Level 1 HTML properties like `myImg.alt= '';` and `myImg.style.verticalAlign= 'middle';` — it's more reliable and nicer to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myImg` is an object, not an HTML string.  What if you try `y[0].appendChild(myImg)` instead?

Comment: ah, my bad, yes, that's the error-fix. I should stop coding today. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) allows you to set the HTML content of a node. However, you are setting it with an element object rather than a string containing HTML. The object gets converted to a string, which is why you see `[object HTMLImageElement]` instead of the image.

To add an element object into page, you an use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild). The following example clears the cell and then appends the image element:

```
y[0].innerHTML = '';
y[0].appendChild(myImg);
```